# Javascript - Div Box as a HyperLink + Nested Text HyperLink - Possible?

Tags: javascript, html, text, hyperlink

Seeing as though Nested Anchor Tags are not possible, could Javascript be utilized to have a Div Box hyperlink to Page-A, while having a word of a Text within the Div Box hyperlink to Page-B?

Have tried working with the following Javascript (works for hyperlinking the Box or the Text, but not both):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  // Content-Link Click Events

  $('.content-link-page-a').click(function(){
    window.location.href = "page-a.html";
  });

  $('.content-link-page-b').click(function(){
    window.location.href = "page-b.html";
  });

</script>
```

Here's some CSS:

```
<style>
  .box {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
  }
</style>
```

And here's the HTML:

```
<div class="box content-link-page-a">
      <div id="username" class="content-link-page-b">UserName</div>
</div><!--/box-->
```

Comment: Nested links are confusing. Don't use them.

Comment: Sure, though the box needs to hyperlink somewhere, and a piece of text in the box needs to link somewhere else, so a solution is needed

Comment: Try to remove the <a> from around the inner DIV, and just for sure, give the inner DIV a bigger z-index in your CSS. Probably it will work that way, because the inner DIV will catch the click event first. Also, probably you should call the e.preventDefault(); in the end of your click handler.

Comment: I read your question, but I'm just saying that you should find a better way to achieve your result. There's a reason nested anchor tags aren't valid HTML.

Comment: @ZoltánTamási ..could you add an answer with z-indexing? Have attempted a simple implementation, but both the box and text still link to PageA (the parent content-link).. have tried with and without the inner-anchor, though without seems the way to go based on everyone's comments and best-practices

Comment: Yes, best practice is to avoid this scenario, but who knows his exact circumstances, and until it's solvable, it's a suitable question and I think should not be downvoted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the A from around the inner DIV, give it a bigger z-index than the outer, and handle the inner click event with calling [event.stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) to prevent bubbling of the event to the outer div. [Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CJa5r/) to solve the task.

Sample for the inner handler:

```
$('.content-link-page-b').click(function(e){
    alert("page-b.html");
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

EDIT: In my comment above, I mentioned e.preventDefault() call. I didn't mean that, because that means the native DOM element's handler will be prevented, and not the jQuery event bubbling.